# Cordova IOS Build Errors (Clean project)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apache, cordova

I have build errors (whenever I try to run the cmd "cordova build ios" or "cordova run ios") the following errorlogs are dumps from "cordova build ios -d".

Here's the error-log i had: http://pastebin.com/WdN7YGBt
Shorter version is beneath.

I have tried changing "Build Active Architecture Only"-setting to "YES" on the CordovaLib-XCODEProject (someone said that resolved their issue) without any success. Can anybody assist me in this case?

--------- Error log ---------

ld: 110 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
        Ld /private/var/root/fearnley_2/platforms/ios/build/emulator/fearnley_2.app/fearnley_2 normal i386

(1 failure)

child_process.spawn(/var/root/fearnley_2/platforms/ios/cordova/build,[]) = 65
Error: An error occurred while building the ios project.** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
        Check dependencies
(1 failure)
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
        Ld /private/var/root/fearnley_2/platforms/ios/build/emulator/fearnley_2.app/fearnley_2 normal i386
(1 failure)

```
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/compile.js:65:22)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
```

Erlend-PC:fearnley_2 root#

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) for development and iOS 7 as target build OS. xCode 5.0.2

Comment: are you able to run `cordova prepare ios`?

Comment: I ran "cordova prepare ios"These are the results I get. Tried to run "cordova build ios" after this one, but failed. @DawsonLoudon

Output:

Erlend-PC:fearnley_2 root# cordova prepare ios
Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "ios"
Preparing ios project

Comment: I have experienced this before, though I have not tracked down the exact cause. After you run the prepare are you able to open the `.xcodeproj` file in xcode and then run on a device or emulator from there?

Comment: Xcode manages to build the project successfully and runs the application. (Using the simulator) @DawsonLoudon

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was experiencing the same issue. First make sure you remove plugins that you suspect might be causing the build to fail issue. For me it was GAPlugin and network-information plugin. To do that run something like:

`cordova plugin remove org.apache.cordova.network-information`

You can find the list of plugins you have installed in the `plugins` directory of your project.

To clean out the build area run:

`./platforms/ios/cordova/clean`

Then run the build command again:

`cordova build ios`